# How to set minimum screen size?

Tags: android

I have created new app, which not for phones. I was based my app to 7" tablet devices.
When I try put my app in play store it show, that my is supported to 2000 android devices, but not all is tablets. Acctually, I don't want google all it devices and set filters, you know why!

How I can progammatically declare mininum screen size in my app, like I can set minimun sdk level.

**Update:**

I was set in AndroidManifest.xml `<compatible-screens>` and `<supports-screens>` like that:

```
<supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
              android:smallScreens="false"
              android:normalScreens="false"
              android:largeScreens="false"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
             />


<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>


</compatible-screens>
```

Now my app is only for 7+ inches tablets.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can define in manifest like this for more detail on [mutliScreenSupport](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

```
 <manifest ... >
        <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
        ...
    </manifest>
```

For market filter you need to use `<compatible-screens>` 
[More Details](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `<supports-screens>` as DJHacktorReborn suggested, but not just `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp`, because the Play Store does not use that for filtering.

Instead, use:

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps) for more.

Comment: you forget to mention about <compatible-screens>

Comment: `<compatible-screens>` has a very specific use case. Even the documentation for it warns you away for most scenarios. It's not necessary for simple size filtering.

Comment: Thanks, that working, I was set 'largeScreens' "false" as well because, I've created app for 7+ inches tablets.

Comment: note that setting `android:largeScreens="true"` means than any device with equal or large **dips** than **640dp x 480dp** will be able to install your app. A 7" tab will have a smallest width of 600dp. With this is mind 640x480dp would roughly be around the **5"** size